# Data-collecting : populate a database offline

Tags: database, mobile, web-applications, offline

I'm currently working with an NGO, and we need to conduct some surveys in the field in Senegal. We want to do it on mobile, but can't rely on 3G connection (high costs and not always reliable).

So, we're looking for a data-collecting/editing tool that :

- is web based;
- works both on mobile and desktop;
- works offline;
- stores it's data in a relational database (mysql, postgres...);
- manages relations;
- can manage geographical input (GPS, custom shapes);
- can manage media input (photos);
- is open source or free/cheap for NGOs.

I thought it would work this way :

1. when online, the user chooses which tables he wants to be able to edit offline
2. those tables are downloaded to the web app's local storage
3. the user can add/edit/delete rows on the local storage, even if offline
4. when back online (at the office), the user can sync back the changes to the server

Any editing of the schema (adding/deleting/changing columns or tables) would have to be done online.

This would work if each record has an UUID, so that two users adding data offline at the same time would not conflict. Of course there's a small chance of conflicts if both users edit the same data, but that wouldn't happen often since each user would work in different zones, and entering data is much more frequent than modifying/deleting data. There could even be a conflict alert by having a "modification uuid".
Of course, if the database grows, the local data would also become quite big. Maybe there would also be the ability to filter which records to sync (eg the last 100 records, or based on geographical boundaries).

The UI would feature :

- a "form" view, to enter or edit data, with widgets corresponding to the field types (ideally including 1 to N relations)
- a "list" view, to have an overview of the data, and do some batch operation
- enventually a "map" view, for tables with geographical data

I know it's quite a lot, but I though it's not possible we're the only organisation needing such a tool.

I found about KoboToolbox in my research of the perfect data-collecting tool. I'm almost satisfied, but there are a few things that are missing for our needs :
- the ability to edit data in the field;
- the ability to build 1-n relations between different forms;
- the ability to populate a database directly (which could be accessed using other tools, like GIS or Access, for display, analysis, or batch modifications).

Does any of you know of such a tool ?
Or are there reasons why they don't exist ?

Thanks a lot !

Olivier

Comment: How about android + sqlite + symmetricDS?

Comment: What do you mean by *the ability to edit data in the field*? You can edit your responses on Android to a form from Kobo if you haven't yet submitted it.

Comment: @Jonathan727 Yes with kobo I can collect data while offline and sync it later, but if I'm not mistaken that doesn't include data with relations (typical of relational databases) nor editing of previously entered data  (eg to make corrections to a previous survey).

Comment: @ Neil yes that stack could work but i was looking for something a bit more high level, where most of the sync/model logic is already taken care of

Answer (score 0):

Ok I came across wq.io which seem to correspond to almost all my specifications.

It's a framework based on top of django, so it still requires quite a lot of technical knowledge, I'm still interested for simpler solutions.

Bests